# How do I switch the database used in a Rails application?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have an application based on the [Devise cancan](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan) repo. Currently it is using SQLite3 as its database.

I was wondering how someone would change the system to something like MongoDB or a SQL database?

And, if I do that, will it create issues while working with the application locally?

Comment: What have you tried, and what isn't working? It's not clear from your question if you don't know where the `database.yml` file is, or if you are running into harder issues.

Comment: Rails, and any well factored application, will separate the configuration data from the code, allowing easy reconfiguration. Rails' use of the database.yml file makes it really easy to change database engines or the host they run on. The added benefit of the file being YAML is it's easy to let other apps reuse the same configuration by loading the same file. Make a change and all affected apps inherit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install and configure another database server, then edit the `config/database.yml` file to point to it. You will also need to include the relevant gem in your gemfile for the adapter chosen:

```
# database.yml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database
  host: localhost
  username: username
  password: password

# gemfile
gem 'pg'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change to MySQL or PostgreSQL easily.

Change your database.yml file, create and run your migrations for your databse. If you want to move existing data, you can export it to to a SQL file and import it, or there are gems to do that for you.

For PostgreSQL, your database.yml will look like this.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
```

Don't forget to add the `pg` or `mysql2` gem to your Gemfile.

For MongoDB you can use Mongoid, it's different than Acive Record.